# Visual Studio jump-to shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What it the Visual Studio shortcut to switch to **recently edited line of code** ? (useful after accidentally pressing Page Down for example).
 I saw my mother using it but couldn't spot what the combination was. Also couldn't find on internet.

Comment: +1 for social skills aka asking mother.

Comment: @froeschli, I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + -</kbd> (that's a hyphen) will take to back to the last place you navigated from.

You can download PDFs of common keyboard shortcuts for visual studio 2010 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en).

Comment: BTW How to create such icon for shortcut?

Comment: @Grant Smith - Tools -> Customize gives you access to the toolbars and commands. You can customize them to your hearts content.

Comment: Sorry i poorly expressed my intention, I meant the icon that your answer starts with (Crtl + -)

Comment: @Grant Smith - It should already be on the standard toolbar, as Navigate Backwards (page with back arrow).

Comment: Oded, I think Grant might be asking about Stackoverflow formatting - how you created the keyboard icon in your answer. The answer is, of course, that you used the `<keybd>` tag like this `<kbd>Ctrl + -</kbd>` Grant, there's more formatting help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: OMG, and I searched by "keyboard shortcuts" or "keyboard hot keys". And Microsoft calls it [keybinding](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189) without any "keyboard" keyword!

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl + -</kbd> will navigate backward. <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + -</kbd> will go forward

Note: This won't work if you use the minus from the keypad

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+Z.  Tools + Options, Text Editor, General.  Tick "Include insertion point movements in Undo list".

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Z will bring you back to where you last edited if you did it by accident.  It will undo the change.

You can also use the bookmark feature of visual studio to bookmark certain lines and then use Ctrl-K, Ctrl-N to go to the next one or Ctrl-K, Ctrl-P to go to the previous one.

Ctrl-= selects from the current location in the editor back to the previous location in the navigation history.

Answer (score 1):

The popular [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) add-in adds a hotkey CTRL+SHIFT+Backspace that brings you back through your history of edit points.